# How to forward multiple arguments from a command in a function?

Tags: vimscript

Given this small vimgrep wrapper, how would I forward multiple arguments to `vimgrep`, so they are interpreted as a single argument to vimgrep?

```
command! -nargs=1 FIND call SimpleGrep(<f-args>)
nnoremap <M-f> :FIND<SPACE>

function! SimpleGrep(exp)
    " Depends on: https://github.com/dbakker/vim-projectroot
    let l:base = ProjectRootGuess()
    " Find files with the current extension in project path.
    let l:root = l:base . "/**/*." . expand('%:e')
    execute 'vimgrep' a:exp l:root
endfunc
```

Currently `FIND text` works, but `FIND "some text"` only works when quoted.

Answer (score 6):

#### The simple case

[Projectroot](https://github.com/dbakker/vim-projectroot) provides the `:ProjectRootExe` command which can simplify this task greatly.

```
command! -nargs=+ FIND ProjectRootExe execute "vimgrep /<args>/ **/*." . expand('%:e')
nnoremap <M-f> :FIND<SPACE>
```

The `<args>` expands to the arguments supplied to your `:FIND` command. While `-nargs=+` means this command can take at least 1 argument. Since you do not want to quote the search pattern we will add `/`'s as suggested by `:h :vimgrep`.

#### Using `<q-args>`

Since you wanted to use a function to do some extra logic, you can use `<q-args>` to slurp up all the arguments into a "quoted string". e.g.

```
function s:simple_grep(pattern)
  let filetypes = {}
  let filetypes['c'] = '{c,cpp,h}'
  execute "ProjectRootExe vimgrep /" . a:pattern . "/ *." . get(filetypes, &filetype, expand('%:e'))
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ Find call <SID>simple_grep(<q-args>)
nnoremap <M-f> :FIND<SPACE>
```

I have added some logic to search multiple extensions when using the `'filetype'` is set to `c`.

#### Alternatives

If you use git and [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) you may want to look into using `:Ggrep` as it much faster than `:vimgrep` and automatically searching from the root of a git project by default.

You may also want to look into using a tool like [Ag the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) which searches recursively by default an can be supplied a file type, e.g. `ag --js 'pattern'`. Note: `ag` does not search from project root. Settings from `man ag`:

```
set grepprg=ag\ --vimgrep\ $*
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

Now you can use `ag` powered grep: `:grep 'pattern'`.

#### For more help see

```
:h :command-nargs
:h <args>
:h :vimgrep
:h :execute
:h expand()
:h <q-args>
:h get()
:h projectroot-:ProjectRootExe
```

Note: I do not use projectroot nor have I tested any of the code above. Use as is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. while this is helpful, I wanted to keep using the function *(instead of bypassing it)*, to be able to choose useful extension(s) based on the filetype.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you can leverage `<q-args>` to pass arguments to a function call.